# Leaflet JS Visualization through static API response using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, frontend, geojson

I'm getting a static response from an API (it returns the same data on every call) and based on that response I'm changing visualization properties of a GeoJSON object.

Currently my workflow is:

1. Read GeoJSON in frontend
2. Hit API to get its response
3. Loop through the api keys and match them with GeoJSON's key. Symbolize based on value when ID gets matched.

The issue with this approach is that on every event, I'm making a new request and getting the same data. Also, after getting the data, the loop takes lots of time to complete and then the visualization property gets applied.

I have tried storing API response in a variable in the frontend code as well but the time taken while looping through the ID's is still a lot. I can't think of any ways to store the visualization properties somewhere to make the symbology change of GeoJSON rapidly.

Some code example to implement this would be helpful. My current code is shared below:

```
$(".ambtn").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        method:"get",
        url:"/los_am",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loader").css({
            display: "inline-block",
            visibility: "visible"
            });
        },
        complete: function(){
            $("#loader").css({
                display: "none",
                visibility: "hidden"
            });
        },
        success:function(res){
            // console.log(res)
            rdNetworkLyr.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                for (const key in res.XDSegID){
                    if(res.XDSegID.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                        if(layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'A'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#060'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'B'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#9f0'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'C'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#ff3'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'D'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#f90'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'E'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#f60'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'F'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#c00'})
                        }
                    }
                }
              });
        }
    });
});
```

My aim is to pass that stored symbology to "setStyle" function without having to loop every time the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

> the loop takes lots of time to complete

> the time taken while looping through the ID's is still a lot

Unless you have *millions* of keys to loop through, the algo part in itself is rarely the bottleneck.

What *may* slow down things is the style change of individual layers in your GeoJSON Layer Group `rdNetworkLyr`: if that makes the browser recompute and repaint the entire Group at every individual change, for sure it will take a lot of work at every step, especially if your group is big!

You can try a simple workaround by removing your `rdNetworkLyr` Layer Group from the map first before applying all the individual style changes, then adding it back:

```js
function (res) {
  rdNetworkLyr.remove();
  // Change all the styles
  rdNetworkLyr.addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your approach but it has no effect on the time. It still takes a lot of time to display the symbology.

Comment: Could you share a live reproduction example, e.g. using [https://leafletjs.com/edit](https://leafletjs.com/edit)?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure how to share the api response as I'm getting that from a database.